# PHP Not operator not working with get_file_contents

Tags: php

Hoping someone could shed some light for me, I'm trying to do a basic if statement on a variable and display error if its not true.

My understanding on the If statement !$variable should evaluate to true if not found and show error, However this is not the case it does not output the echo and shows just a debug saying file cannot be found etc...

I did manage to fix this with just $variable === true then output error in the else statement but just want to know why this below doesn't work.

```
$variable = file_get_contents("file.txt");

if(!$variable){
   echo ("Error");
} else {
echo "<p>{$variable}</p>";
}
```

Comment: use a fully qualified path and file_exists to check existance of the file

Comment: use $variable === false instead !$variable

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://onlinephp.io?s=s7EvyCjg5VIpSyzKTEzKSVWwVUjLzEmNT08tiU_OzytJzSsp1lACCemVVJQoaVrzcvFyZaZpKMJ1aFbzcikoKKQmZ-QraCi5FhXlF4GV1Sqk5hSnKgBlwVJKNgV21XBNtTb6BXZKIFW8XAA%2C&v=8.1.11), Error is shown as expected.

Comment: @AsmaMech Thankyou for your response, do you buy chance know why the above does not evaluate properly as a boolean? the file_get_contents(); should return a false according to this > https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp

Comment: _"I did manage to fix this with just $variable === true"_ - I don't see how that function could ever return `true`, regardless of the file existing or not. As the document states, it can only return `string|false`. That would mean the check is useless and will always execute the `else` branch of your `if`-statement.

Comment: What you see is a normal E_WARNING type error. But also it must evaluate `!$variable` as true, so it must do the echo "Error". Are you sure it doesn't shown?

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP it does show error, but still shows the echo error message even if the path is found. its blowing my brain up haha.

Comment: here is an explanation with both cases : https://3v4l.org/N3vqY

Comment: If the file is empty, `$variable` it will be empty string so evaluated false. To avoid this, use `===`. Also, ensure you can read the file (check permissions). When I need `file_get_contents`, I use to first call `file_exists`, `is_file` and `is_readable` functions.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP ok thankyou for the assist, i had the number 0 in the file and that returned as a false when calling the txt file too, so after i changed it to 2000 to test that !$variable finaly works the way its supposed to but if it returns 0 i thinks its false.

Comment: This must do the job even when zero: `if ($variable === false) {`. Remember that `0`, `'0'`, `''`, `' '` are evaluated as false.